# CarPlay NowPlaying screen shows wrong image on Dark appearance when using CPNowPlayingImageButton

Tags: ios, carplay

I am developing CarPlay app using CarPlay framework.
I use CPNowPlayingImageButton to display custom button on NowPlaying template.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cpnowplayingimagebutton?language=objc
Created ImageAsset image,
[image: ImageAsset]

Then create CPNowPlayingImageButton.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"carplay_heart" inBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] compatibleWithTraitCollection:self.interfaceController.carTraitCollection];

CPNowPlayingImageButton* button = [CPNowPlayingImageButton.alloc initWithImage:image handler:^(CPNowPlayingImageButton*)
{
    JPlaylistUtils::CurrentToggleFavorite(FALSE, TRUE, nil);
}];

[CPNowPlayingTemplate.sharedTemplate updateNowPlayingButtons:@[button]];
```

I expected black image on light appearance, and white image on dark appearance, but CarPlay displays always black (light theme) image on the dark appearance, and image size is too small.

[image: screenshot]

If I change Appearance at CarPlay / Settings, image is displayed as expected at first time.
[image]

But if update the button, CarPlay displays wrong image again.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to only use one image and let CarPlay figure out light/dark mode tinting by setting the Render As to Template Image. Which sizes do your images have?

Comment: Render As to Template setting solves the color problem, but size is still small when updating the button. Image was 72x72@2x previously, current size is 40x40@2x, 60x60@3x, following the CPNowPlayingButtonMaximumImageSize.

Comment: is there any solution for update changes?

Comment: Apparently, this fix only partially solves the problem. Upon an update, the icon will be downscaled, but this does not occur if the image is larger than 21pt.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
UIImage(systemName: "heart")
```

where a system image alternative exists... it tints as desired